# Mysql procedure issue, out or range or No data

Tags: mysql, procedure, mysql-error-1064, declare

I'm trying to write a mysql procedure to fix a problem of my database.

Currently there are two tables related with this issue:

pre_forum_thread    -  This is the table which keeps the information about how many replies are linked to a post.

pre_forum_post  - This is the post database.

The procedure I wrote is as following:

```
delimiter //
create procedure fix_position()
begin
    declare t int(10);
    declare b int(10);
    declare c int(10);
    DECLARE thread_id CURSOR FOR select tid from pre_forum_thread;
    open thread_id;
        fetch thread_id into t;
        SELECT count(*) into b FROM pre_forum_post WHERE tid=t;
        set c= b - 1;
        UPDATE pre_forum_thread SET replies= c WHERE tid=t;
        UPDATE pre_forum_thread SET maxposition=b WHERE tid=t;
    CLOSE thread_id;
end;//
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I call this procedure, I got error:

```
    Out of range value for column 'replies' at row 1
```

And I change the procedure to

```
DECLARE thread_id CURSOR FOR select tid from pre_forum_thread;
    open thread_id;
        fetch thread_id into t;
        SELECT count(*) into b FROM pre_forum_post WHERE tid=t;
        UPDATE pre_forum_thread SET maxposition=b WHERE tid=t;
    CLOSE thread_id;
```

I got error

```
ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

Looks like both "update" is not working...
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show some sample data to support the updates?

Comment: If `tid` starts at 1, then `1 - 1 = 0`, so `replies` row would generate that error.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Here is an example which I can run manually: 

    SELECT count(*)  FROM pre_forum_post WHERE tid=1978593;     

will get 3, then I can run below sql to update database:

    UPDATE pre_forum_thread SET replies='2' WHERE tid=1978593;
    UPDATE pre_forum_thread SET maxposition='3' WHERE tid=1978593;